# Referential transparency confusion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, referential-transparency

First up, despite this being an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes this is not a homework question. I can find implementations of the Sieve in many intro books :).

The question I have is that around my confusion around referential transparency, which was one of the virtues of functional programming.

My understanding was that I could replace `f(x)` anywhere in my program with `y`, provided `y = f(x)` and I was in a pure function.

A naive implementation of the n-th prime using the Sieve "by hand" is

```hs
nums0 = [2..]  -- allowed by lazy evaluation
nums1 = [n | n <- nums0, mod n (head nums0) /= 0] -- works, gives [3,5,7,9,11,13,15...]
nums2 = [n | n <- nums1, mod n (head nums1) /= 0] -- works, gives [5,7,11,13,...]
nums3 = [n | n <- nums2, mod n (head nums2) /= 0] -- works, gives [7,11,13,...]
```

It is clear that there is a recursive pattern here. Let's call `ndnp m` the function that returns the list of natural numbers greater than 1 that are not divisible by the first `m` primes i.e.

```hs
nums0 = ndnp 0  -- (i.e. all numbers starting at 2)
nums1 = ndnp 1  -- (not divisible by 2)
nums2 = ndnp 2  -- (not divisible by 2 or 3)
```

To find the Nth prime, we can simply do `head $ ndnp (n-1)`.

The example of constructing the `numsX` array has a recursive structure:

```hs
-- ndnp: Not Divisible by first N Primes
ndnp :: Integer -> [Integer]
ndnp 0 = [2..]
ndnp n = [n | n <- (ndnp (n-1)), mod n (head $ ndnp (n-1)) /= 0]
```

In particular, `ndnp 1` is built from `ndnp 0` or `nums0`

When run `take 10 $ ndnp 0` I get the answer I expect. When I run `take 10 $ ndnp 1` I get a stackoverflow.

My question:

- I can assign just fine: `a = ndnp 1` is legal. Evaluation is lazy, which I understand.
- When I try `take`, I get a stack overflow (which suggests it is trying to evaluate the whole structure). I could understand if `mod` or something forced eager evaluation, but I know this isn't the case because ...
- `take 10 nums1` works just fine, and it is build off the same steps of looping through an infinite, lazily eval'ed list!
- Since `nums0 = ndnp 0`, why is the execution of `take 10 $ nums1` fine (which uses `nums0` and iterates over it), but `take 10 $ ndnp 1` broken (which uses the result of `ndnp 0` and iterates over it)? Referrential transparency suggests I should be able to swap one out for the other, but in one case I retain lazy evaluation and the other generates a stack overflow!

Note:
There is a fix for this I found

```hs
ndnp :: Integer -> [Integer]
ndnp 0 = [2..]
ndnp n = [n | n <- arr, mod n (head $ arr) /= 0]
     where arr = ndnp (n-1)
```

which makes my code work, but doesn't give me a good conceptual understanding on when I have referential transparency and when I don't.

Comment: The `n`  declared inside the list comprehension is shadowing the `n` declared in the function definition. It's causing infinite recursion. Use `[ m | m <- ....`

Comment: Interesting question, boring answer.  You just need to remember to do capture-avoiding substitution.

Comment: You say "referential transparency suggests I should be able to swap one [`take 10 $ nums1`] for the other [`take 10 $ ndnp 1`]". This *would* be true if we knew `nums1 = ndnp 1`, or vice versa `ndnp 1 = nums1`. But neither of those is an equation you have in your program text, so if you want to do that swap you have to first prove that equation from the ones you *do* have. (This is not meant to be enlightening, but rather to be an explanation of what went wrong mechanically in your thinking.)

Comment: To put it another way: which entity a name refers to is not necessarily transparent even with referential transparency. Reusing names is risky.

Comment: @DanielWagner, it isn’t just the results that are the same, but the method of construction that is the same. Nums0 and ndnp 0 match exactly, and at least at the first level of recursion nums1 and ndnp 1 are constructed “the same way”

Comment: The reason for the quotes is the because of what @4castlepoints out — that I inadvertently shadowed the name n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have warnings turned on (which is good practice -- it's kind of a mystery to me that so many compilers, GHC included, default to *not* printing warnings), then you'll see something like:

```
Referential.hs:6:15: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘n’ shadows the existing binding
      bound at Referential.hs:6:6
  |
6 | ndnp n = [n | n <- (ndnp (n-1)), mod n (head $ ndnp (n-1)) /= 0]
                  ^
```

which will clue you in on what's going wrong.  The Haskell scoping rules mean that your original definition of `ndnp` is equivalent to:

```
ndnp n = [m | m <- (ndnp (n-1)), mod m (head $ ndnp (m-1)) /= 0]
          ^   ^                      ^               ^
```

That is, your new definition of `n` *doesn't* capture the `n` in the first occurrence of `ndnp (n-1)`, but it does capture all the other `n`s in the comprehension.

When you try to evaluate `ndnp 1` you get:

```
ndnp 1 = [m | m <- ndnp 0, mod m (head $ ndnp (m-1)) /= 0]
```

and the list comprehension starts with `m = 2` which calls `ndnp (m-1) = ndnp 1` within the guard, resulting in an infinite loop.

You can fix the problem by renaming the newly introduced iteration variable in the list comprehension:

```
ndnp n = [n' | n' <- (ndnp (n-1)), mod n' (head $ ndnp (n-1)) /= 0]
```

Observe that substituting `n = 1` gives:

```
ndnp 1 = [n' | n' <- ndnp 0, mod n' (head $ ndnp 0) /= 0]
```

and then substituting `ndnp 0 = nums0` gives:

```
ndnp 1 = [n' | n' <- nums0, mod n' (head nums0) /= 0]
```

which precisely matches your definition of `nums1` up to variable substitution.

So, there's no violation of referential transparency in this example.

The fix you found:

```
ndnp n = [n | n <- arr, mod n (head $ arr) /= 0]
     where arr = ndnp (n-1)
```

is scoped differently.  The Haskell scoping rules mean that it's equivalent to:

```
ndnp n = [m | m <- arr, mod m (head $ arr) /= 0]
          ^   ^             ^
     where arr = ndnp (n-1)
```

See how the new variable `m` captures every occurrence of `m` in the list comprehension, but *doesn't* capture the `n` in the definition of `arr`?  This means that this is equivalent to:

```
ndnp n = [m | m <- ndnp (n-1), mod m (head $ ndnp (n-1)) /= 0]
          ^   ^                    ^
```

where neither `ndnp (n-1)` is captured, making it equivalent to my "fixed" version above, up to variable renaming:

```
ndnp n = [n' | n' <- (ndnp (n-1)), mod n' (head $ ndnp (n-1)) /= 0]
          ^^   ^^                      ^^
```